# i want to import csv file into two different controller models ..can this be possible

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

i have 5 field in which 4 field should in one table and last column should import in another table

```
 def self.import(file)

   CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

 lock_store_hash = row.to_hash
 lock_store = LockStore.where(id: lock_store_hash["id"])

 if lock_store.count == 1
   lock_store.first.update_attributes(lock_store_hash.except(params[:file][:taxon_id]))
 else
   LockStore.create!(lock_store_hash)
 end
   end
 end
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, in your case you could do something like this (I'm assuming you have a belong_to and has_many between your models):

```
...
if lock_store.count == 1
   lock_store.first.update_attributes(lock_store_hash.except(params[:file][:taxon_id]))
   # the update code I will let to you because is difficult to assume based in the information provided
else
   lockstore = LockStore.create!(lock_store_hash)
   lockstore.another_models.create(attribute_name: lock_store_hash[:last_column])
end
```